# How to Simplify my SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm fairly new to SQL and was wondering if there is a way to simplify one of my SQL queries.

```
SELECT 
    ships.ship_name,
    ships.company_name,
    ports.port_name,
    ports.port_country,
    port_days.port_date AS port_days 
FROM 
    port_days, ships, ports 
WHERE 
    port_days.ship_id = ships.ship_id 
    AND port_days.port_id = ports.port_id 
    AND port_days.ship_id = '" . $ship_id . "'
    AND port_days.port_date > '" . $start_date . "'
    AND port_days.port_date < '" . $end_date . "'
```

I was playing around with `INNER JOIN` but couldn't get it to work. This is actually working but I'm thinking there must be a better way??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use explicit `JOIN` and table aliases:

```
SELECT s.ship_name, s.company_name,
       p.port_name, p.port_country, p.port_date as port_days 
FROM port_days pd JOIN
     ships s
     ON pd.ship_id = s.ship_id JOIN
     ports p
     ON pd.port_id = p.port_id
WHERE pd.ship_id = '" . $ship_id . "' AND
      pd.port_date > '" . $start_date . "' AND
      pd.port_date < '" . $end_date . "';
```